# Display ONLY Tier Price based on Customer Group in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm building a B2B site and I need to display the tier price matched to each customer's customer group rather than the default price of a product. I need this tier price to be displayed as the primary price of the product for the customer. Many of the customer groups' tier prices are higher than the default price. 
Each Customer has a Customer Group to match. Customer Groups have different prices for each product. 
Does anyone have a suggestion on how to pull this off?

We're on Magento 1.9 CE

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Magento will always show the user the loswest price by default, so I would suggest setting the 'standard' price to the product RRP, which (I imagine) will be higher than all tier prices and encourage the b2b customers to login to see their price.

Tier prices can set assigned by customer group.  Take a look at Magmi for importing and managing the values really quickly from a csv.  Note the column header should be the name of your group rather than its group ID.

Comment: Ok, so I'll need to set the standard prices higher than all tiers.

Comment: Is there a way to make the the Tier Price for the signed in Customer be displayed as the Price of the product rather than as a discount?

Comment: 2 options. 1 set the group price (non tiered) to the price for a single unit, so atleast the discount will look more natural.  2. modify the tierprices.phtml which will either be here: app/design/frontend/XXX/YYY/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml (where XXX/YYY is your theme directory) OR if its not there, copy this one to your theme directory here app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml